# what precaution should do when table rename?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, rename, conflict

Sometimes, insertion error may occur because of the rename a table.
Anybody can share any procedure should do before or after the rename of the table.

Example:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "ForignKeyName". The conflict occurred in database "DB", table
>   "TABLE", column 'COLUMN'.

Comment: As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 "Changing any part of an object name can break scripts and stored procedures. We recommend you do not use this statement to rename stored procedures, triggers, user-defined functions, or views; instead, drop the object and re-create it with the new name."

Comment: That error has nothing to do with renaming tables. You are breaking a constraint due to data.

Answer (score 1):

Found all the foreign keys and alter the constraint. For that, All the referenced table should know.

The below query list all the constraints which refer to the renamed table.
Please alter constraints from the respective table.

```
 SELECT
      f.name constraint_name
      ,OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) referencing_table_name
      ,COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id 
      ,fc.parent_column_id) referencing_column_name
      ,OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) referenced_table_name
      ,COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id
      ,fc.referenced_column_id) referenced_column_name
      ,delete_referential_action_desc
      ,update_referential_action_desc
 FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
 INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc
   ON f.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id
   where       
   OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) ='RENAMEING_TABLE_NAME' -- deleting/ renaming table 
 ORDER BY f.name
```

Comment: it will helpful for those who are creating a table and renaming old table instead of updating.